# How to mention plugins in CKEditor 5 configuration file

Tags: ckeditor5

In CKEditor 4 we can use below configuration to add additional plugins. How can we achieve it in ckeditor 5?

```js
toolbar: [
      { name: 'document', items: ['Source', '-', 'DocProps', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates'] },
      { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
      { name: 'editing', items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'] },
      { name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks', '-', ] },
        '/',
      { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'] },
      { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor'] },
      { name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent',
       '-', 'Blockquote', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl'] },
        '/',
      { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'] },
      { name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'] }
    ]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually incorrect. In CKEditor 4, you add new plugins using [extraPlugins](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-extraPlugins) setting. What you have shown above is [toolbar](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-toolbar) configuration which you can read more about here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_toolbarconcepts.html.

If you wish to add new plugins to CKEditor 5, please see: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installing-plugins.html#adding-a-plugin-to-a-build and https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editorconfig-EditorConfig.html#member-plugins.

If you wish to configure toolbar in CKEditor 5 and add new buttons to it, please see: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/configuration.html#toolbar-setup and https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editorconfig-EditorConfig.html#member-toolbar.